# tikz: 2 vertical coordinate system

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I need for my Bachelorthesis this figure:
[image]

**Edit:** *(Sorry, I didn't know that I should edit my posting and don't add another answer.)*

**Edit 2:**

Thanks for all the responses.

Here is the code if someone is interested:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing,angles,quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \coordinate (o);

    \draw [->] (-.5,0) -- (7,0) coordinate (a) node [right] {$\alpha$};
    \draw [->] (0,-.5) -- (0,6) coordinate (jb) node [above] {j$\beta$};

    \begin{scope}[rotate=30]
        \draw [draw=orange,->] (-.5,0) -- (6,0) coordinate (d) node [right] {$d$};
        \draw [draw=orange,->] (0,-.5) -- (0,6) coordinate (jq) node [above] {j$q$};;
    \end{scope}

    \path (2.4,5.5) coordinate (z) node [above left] {$\underline{z}$};
    \draw [draw=black,->,line width=0.6mm] (o) -- (z);
    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3mm}] (0,0) -- node[sloped,above=3mm] {$|\underline{z}|$} (2.4,5.5);      

    \draw [draw=blue,dotted]
    ($(o)!(z)!(jb)$) coordinate (zb) node [left] {$z_\beta$} -- (z) -- 
    ($(o)!(z)!(a)$) coordinate (za) node [below] {$z_\alpha$};
    \draw [draw=orange,dashed]
    ($(o)!(z)!(jq)$) coordinate (zq) node [left] {$z_q$} -- (z) -- 
    ($(o)!(z)!(d)$) coordinate (zd) node [below] {$z_d$};
    \draw [draw=blue,dotted]
    (za) -- ($(z)!(za)!(zd)$) coordinate (x) -- (z);
    \draw [draw=blue,dotted]
    (za) -- ($(o)!(za)!(zd)$) coordinate (x) -- (zd);   

    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,amplitude=1.2mm}] (x) -- node[sloped,above=-6mm,font=\footnotesize] {$z_\alpha \sin\gamma$} (za);
    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,amplitude=3mm}] (za) -- node[sloped,above=-9mm,font=\small] {$z_\beta \sin\gamma$} ($(z)!(za)!(zd)$); 
    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3mm}] (z) -- node[sloped,above=2mm,font=\small] {$z_\beta \cos\gamma$} ($(z)!(za)!(zd)$);
    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3mm}] (o) -- node[sloped,above right=1mm of d,font=\small] {$z_\alpha \cos\gamma$} ($(za)!(zd)!(x)$);

    \draw [draw=black,->] (0:1.2) arc (0:26:1.4) node [left,pos=0.38,font=\small] {$\gamma$};
    \draw [draw=black,->] (2.4,4.5) arc (-180:0:0.29cm) node [left,pos=1.3,font=\small] {$\gamma$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the output:
[image]

Comment: To have nodes parallel to the lines along which they're positioned, add the `sloped` option to the node (and replace `right` with `above`). Regarding the gap between the line and the brace, your code already has the answer to that: You have specified that the braces should be moved 3pt away from the coordinates with the `raise` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a solution only by the right parenthesis, I let you modify the others.

a remark, your sample code does not work, it lacks the libraries (and I delete the german)

you will notice, that I have added in the node the angle of rotation of the text (90 + 30) and modified the positioning

for the offset, I removed the raise in the path of the parenthesis.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing,angles,quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \coordinate (o);

    \draw [->] (-.5,0) -- (6,0) coordinate (a) node [right] {$\alpha$};
    \draw [->] (0,-.5) -- (0,6) coordinate (jb) node [above] {j$\beta$};

    \begin{scope}[rotate=30]
        \draw [draw=orange,->] (-.5,0) -- (6,0) coordinate (d) node [right] {$d$};
        \draw [draw=orange,->] (0,-.5) -- (0,6) coordinate (jq) node [above] {j$q$};;
    \end{scope}

    \path (2.4,5) coordinate (z) node [above left] {$\underline{z}$};
    \draw [draw=black,->,line width=0.8mm] (o) -- (z);      

    \draw [draw=blue,dotted]
    ($(o)!(z)!(jb)$) coordinate (zb) node [left] {$z_\beta$} -- (z) -- 
    ($(o)!(z)!(a)$) coordinate (za) node [below] {$z_\alpha$};
    \draw [draw=orange,dashed]
    ($(o)!(z)!(jq)$) coordinate (zq) node [left] {$z_q$} -- (z) -- 
    ($(o)!(z)!(d)$) coordinate (zd) node [below] {$z_d$};
    \draw [draw=blue,dotted]
    (za) -- ($(z)!(za)!(zd)$) coordinate (x) -- (z);
    \draw [draw=blue,dotted]
    (za) -- ($(o)!(za)!(zd)$) coordinate (x) -- (zd);   

    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=3pt}] (x) -- node[left,font=\small] {$z_\alpha \sin\gamma_N$} (za);
    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=3pt}] (za) -- node[right,font=\small] {$z_\beta \sin\gamma_N$} ($(o)!(za)!(zd)$); 
    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace}] (z) -- node[,rotate={30+90},below=0.5em,font=\small] {$z_\beta \cos\gamma_N$} ($(o)!(z)!(d)$);
    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,raise=3pt}] (o) -- node[left,font=\small] {$z_\alpha \cos\gamma_N$} ($(za)!(zd)!(x)$);


    \draw [draw=black, ->] (0:1.4) arc (0:30:1.4) node [left,pos=0.3,font=\small] {$\gamma_N$};
    \draw [draw=black, ->] (z) arc (0:-30:1.4) node [left,pos=0.3] {$\gamma_\text{N}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Things become a lot easier when using the `calc` library as the following (incomplete) example shows:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\coordinate (O);
\draw [->] (-.5,0) -- (5,0) coordinate (a) node [below] {$\alpha$};
\draw [->] (0,-.5) -- (0,5) coordinate (jb) node [left] {$j_\beta$};
\begin{scope}[rotate=30]
\draw [draw=orange, ->] (-.5,0) -- (5,0) coordinate (d) node [below] {$d$};
\draw [draw=orange, ->] (0,-.5) -- (0,5) coordinate (jq) node [left] {$j_q$};;
\end{scope}
\path (2,4) coordinate (Z) node [above right] {$Z$};
\draw [draw=blue, dotted]
  ($(O)!(Z)!(jb)$) coordinate (Zb) node [left] {$Z_\beta$} --
  (Z) -- 
  ($(O)!(Z)!(a)$) coordinate (Za) node [below] {$Z_\alpha$};
\draw [draw=orange, dashed]
  ($(O)!(Z)!(jq)$) coordinate (Zq) node [left] {$Z_q$} --
  (Z) -- 
  ($(O)!(Z)!(d)$) coordinate (Zd) node [below] {$Z_d$};
\draw [draw=blue, dotted]
  (Za) -- ($(Z)!(Za)!(Zd)$) coordinate (x) -- (Z);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]